# Track data load history in Snowflake

Tags: sql, metadata, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Snowflake stores few metadata sets in its INFORMATION_SCHEMA object. I tried to investigate how specific table got loaded by procedure/query.

`History` allows to investigate high-level but I wanted to have custom SQL code to drill more deep.
[image]

After executing below code i got `Statement not found` error even though Query_ID is valid.
Is there any way to navigate history load so I can track what procedure loaded data to which table?

```
SELECT * FROM table(RESULT_SCAN('xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

details of using RESULT_SCAN( ) can be found at the below link, please note these two conditions might be affecting your ability to run the query:

- the query cannot have executed more than 24 hours prior to the use of RESULT_SCAN()
- only the user who ran the original query can use the RESULT_SCAN( )

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/result_scan.html#usage-notes

As for *"navigate history load so I can track what procedure loaded data to which table?"*:   I'd strongly recommend you doing your analysis on the SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.QUERY_HISTORY view.
A good starting point might be something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   snowflake.account_usage.query_history
WHERE  start_time >= DATEADD('days', -30, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
AND    start_time <= date_trunc(HOUR, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
AND    query_text iLike '%TABLE_NAME_HERE%'
AND    query_type <> 'SELECT';
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/query_history.html

If you suspect the table in question has been loaded from a COPY INTO table command, 
it'd make sense for you to begin with seeing the results of those in one of the following two views:

- SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.COPY_HISTORY  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/copy_history.html
- SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.LOAD_HISTORY  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/load_history.html

While the views in the account_usage "share" may have some latency (typically 10-20 minutes, could be as much as 90 minutes), I've found that using them to do analysis like you are doing easier than querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA objects (opinion).

I hope this helps...Rich

Comment: I will request turning on `account_usage` :)

Comment: This made my day!!

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to view the most recent query history you can use the following syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE(information_schema.QUERY_HISTORY())
WHERE QUERY_ID = 'xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

To filter for data load queries:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE(information_schema.QUERY_HISTORY())
WHERE QUERY_TEXT LIKE '%COPY INTO%'
```

Tip: The above table functions return the last 7 days worth of data. If you require more history, use the Account usage views.
Tip: to use the Account History views, switch to the AccountAdmin role.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/query_history.html

Rgds,

Dan.

Comment: Thanks but first query you provided is not working. It seems that date parameters are working in some unusual way for this object.

Comment: It may be the session timezone. 

You can check this using:

    SHOW PARAMETERS LIKE 'TIMEZONE';

You can change the setting e.g.:

    ALTER SESSION SET TIMEZONE = 'UTC';

e.g:

    SELECT *
    FROM TABLE(information_schema.QUERY_HISTORY(
 END_TIME_RANGE_START=>to_timestamp_ltz('2020-06-16 11:38:08') 
 , END_TIME_RANGE_END=>to_timestamp_ltz('2020-06-16 13:38:08'))
 );

Could you check if this works for you?

Comment: The issue is different. END_TIME_RANGE parameter is a hard lock for only those jobs that execute within that fixed timeframe. Expanding this range for entire day shouldn't work as there are no jobs that run totally half day.

Comment: Thanks marcin2x4. Not specifying END_TIME_RANGE_START will return both complete and also still running queries. Information_schema.QUERY_HISTORY returns 100 rows by default. This can be increased using RESULT_LIMIT e.g. 

SELECT *
FROM TABLE(information_schema.QUERY_HISTORY(
 END_TIME_RANGE_START=>to_timestamp_ltz('2020-06-16 11:38:08') 
 , RESULT_LIMIT => 10000));
 
Does this help?

Comment: Partially as my jobs don't take many hours. When eliminating RANGE parameters I get only last two hours of data due to fact that most recent ones are taken into account.

Comment: No problem, also thank you for help. ACOUNT_USAGE schema in Snowflake share is the best solution ;)